# Counting graphs with even degrees

Tags: graph-theory

How many <del>non-isomorphic</del> distinct labeled 5-vertex graphs with even degrees are there? The answer is $2^6$, but I don't seem to be able to solve the problem.

P.S. It's not a homework. I'm just studying for an exam.

Comment: Just speculation, because I can't prove it at the moment.  The edge space of $K_5$ has $2^{10}$ members, since it is a vector space over $\mathbb F_2$ with a basis of order $10$.  The cut space will have $1+5+10=16$ members ($5 C 0 + 5 C 1 + 5 C 2$).  The cycle space, which is what you want, is the orthogonal complement of the cut space and has $\frac{2^{10}}{2^4} = 2^6$ members.  And you distinguish between isomorphic graphs.  You're not looking for graphs up to isomorphism.

Comment: @AndrewSalmon Yes, you're right. The original question was in Persian and I mistranslated "distinct" to "non-isomorphic". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are looking, essentially, for the cycle space of $K_5$, the set of all graphs formed from disjoint unions of cycles.  This fact follows by strong induction on the number of edges: since all degrees are even, the components of the graph cannot be trees, so it must contain a cycle if it is nonempty.

The cycle space is the orthogonal complement of the cut space in the edge space (which is a vector space over $\mathbb F_2$).  The order of the edge space is easy enough to calculate, and it corresponds to all possible graphs with $5$ vertices (not up to isomorphism).  It has order $2^{10}$ since for any graph $G$, each of $10$ edges of $K_5$ can be in $E(G)$ or not in $E(G)$.

The cut space contains the empty graph, $5$ copies of $K_{1,4}$ and $10$ copies of $K_{2,3}$, so it has $16$ graphs in total.  Since it is a subspace of $\mathcal E(G)$, it has a basis of order $4$.  So the cycle space has $2^{10} / 2^4 = 2^6$ members.

Comment: This generalizes to any number of vertices, right ?

Comment: Yes.  It does.  In general, the basis of the cycle space has order $|E|-|V|+1$.  Source: http://www.cs.du.edu/~ramki/downloads/papers/circulationsPreprint.pdf Proposition 3

Answer (score 0):

There's a bijection between the labelled graphs on $n-1$ vertices and the labelled graphs on $n$ vertices with all even degrees (as I described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361650/counting-graphs-with-even-degrees-trouble-with-formula/361806#361806)).  Since there are $2^{\binom{n-1}{2}}$ labelled graphs with $n-1$ vertices, when $n=5$, there are $2^{\binom{4}{2}}=2^6$ labelled graphs with all even degrees.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by a non-isomorphic labelled graph?

In terms of just 5-vertex graphs, there is one up to isomorphism with no edges, 1 with 3 edges, 1 with 4 edges,  1 with 5 edges, 1 with 6 edges, 1 with 7 edges, 1 with 10 edges.  A total of 7

Edit:  Sorry forgot the 5-cycle :)

Comment: I downvoted this because : 1) You’re mistaking “all degrees even” for “even number of edges” 2) Your statements are grossly false

Comment: Sorry I don't see how what I said is false, I merely forgot to include the 5 cycle.

Comment: The question asked for graphs different up to isomorphism.  I see now he actually didn't want it up to isomorphism at all but rather different graphs on the same set of labels.