# The number of labelled graphs with all vertices of even degree

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

I have a graph exam tomorrow, and there is a problem that said number of graph with labeled vertices and all of them of even degree is $ 2^{n-1 \choose 2} $.

According to that topic, it means the number of cut spaces is $ 2^{n-1} $.
Well, I don't understand what is cut space yet, and why its count is $ 2^{n-1} $ And don't  know why we should divide the total number of graphs by this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first question, the hint should be $2^{\binom{n-1}{2}}$; it counts the number of labelled graphs on $n-1$ vertices.

There's a bijection between the $2^{\binom{n-1}{2}}$ labelled graphs $G$ on $n-1$ vertices on the vertex set $\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ and labelled graphs on $n$ vertices with even degree $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, namely add in the vertex $n$ and connect it to the odd-degree vertices in $G$.  There cannot be an odd number of odd-degree vertices in $G$, as this would violate the [Handshaking Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma), so the new vertex will also have even degree.

I don't know what a cut space is either; what does it say in your books/notes?  (I'd guess though, that the $2^{n-1}$ is coming from the number of subsets of vertices that have even cardinality.)

Comment: your solution was very helpful and i really like the way that you look to the problem!
just one question! how to prove every graph that create by adding the n'th node, is unique!?

Comment: Indeed, we should check that.  If two $n$-vertex graphs created in this way were equal, then we delete the vertex $n$ and obtain the same $(n-1)$-vertex graph.  So the two graphs were formed in the same way.

Comment: tnx bro, 
it was my last exam question, and i solved it by your elegant solution.