# Number of labeled graphs of $n$ odd degree vertices

Tags: graph-theory

[The number of labelled graphs with all vertices of even degree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361650/counting-graphs-with-even-degrees-trouble-with-formula)

This question is about number of labeled graphs of $n$ even vertices. I need hint how to find number of labeled graphs of $n$ odd degree vertices. It is clear that answer is $0$ when $n$ is odd.

Comment: I do not get why number of the  graph with $n$ vertex is zero when $n$ is odd. Did you mean something else?

Comment: all vertices should have odd degree, by odd vertices I mean vertices of odd degree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be the same number as the # of graphs with even degree vertices (so according to the question you linked $2^{\binom{n-1}{2}}$ in case $n$ is even).

This is true because, there is a bijection between the graphs where all vertex degrees are even and the graphs where all vertex degrees are odd: Let $G$ be a graph that has only vertices with even degree, and let $\bar G$ be its complement. Clearly ($n$ is even), a single vertex $v$ has $n-1$ possible neighbors, which is an odd number. Since $\deg_G(v)$ is an even number, $\deg_{\bar G}(v)$ has to be an odd number.

Answer (score 1):

Think the adjacency matrix of a graph.

Let $A$ be $n\times n$ matrice such that $A_{ij}\in \{0,1\}$ , $A_{ii}=0$ and $A^T=A$. Then you can say that there  are $2^{n(n-1)\over2}$ such matrices as it is enough to fill lower triangle part of matrices.

But  you want that $deg(v_i)$ is odd then it means that sum of every cloumn is odd.

Now, fill every cloumn except the last one in lower triangle part. Then you can see that your condition uniqly determine the last one. (if it is already odd put $0$, if not $1$).  Thus, answer is equal to find number of such matrices with $(n-1)x(n-1)$ dimension.

Hence, result is $2^{(n-1)(n-2)\over 2}$ as above argument shows.

Comment: I am not asking this, I need to find the number of such graphs, when n is even

Comment: @Ashot: I misunderstood again , sorry Now I got what you mean.

Comment: @Ashot: Do you have condition such that the graph is connected ?

Comment: No, it can be any graph

Comment: @Ashot: I fixed the answer.