# Exact counting of odd graphs

Tags: graph-theory, alternative-proof

Earlier today, a badly posed graph theory question was down-voted and removed. However, when shorn of its chrome and properly phrased, the question surprisingly has an exact answer! So I thought it would be worth re-posting for the first poster to see.

Essentially, the question asked how many vertex-labeled graphs are there such that every vertex has odd degree.

The answer was requested for 50 vertices, and turns out to be:

> $2^{49 \choose 2} = 2^{1176}$

First, all-odd can only work if the number of vertices is even. In which case we can also count the complementary graphs where all degrees are even. And this will work for any number of vertices. Next, the set of cycles (considered over the field Z_2) generates the set of even graphs as a vector space. A basis for this vector space is found by picking a vertex h as the hub, and considering the C(n-1,2) 3-cycles (h,x,y) for all vertices x&y not equal to h. These are all independent because for each 3-cycle, there is an edge xy to which it is the only contributor. So the vector-space has dimension C(n-1,2) and there are 2^C(n-1,2) even graphs.

Has anyone got a nice elementary proof of this?

Comment: @Hagen: how do I structure this repost then? Just put the answer in the question? That seemed a greater distortion of the basic model. Really the original question should not have been deleted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a question.

Comment: You could ask for a nice proof for this result. I did this before. Worked out well and your might learn something in the progress. There is even a tag "alternative-proof".

Comment: I like M. Winter's constructive suggestion, and will add this form to make it a proper question.

Comment: @Laska How have you found this number in your question?

Comment: @M.Winter: it was essentially a more formal version of Hagen's solution. I guess I should put it in the original post, since I am asking for alternatives now.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361650/the-number-of-labelled-graphs-with-all-vertices-of-even-degree

Comment: @Qudit - it's pretty close. The question focus there is more on cut-spaces. Time to move on from this one in any case.

Answer (score 2):

Start with $K_n$ over the vertices $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$. Assign an arbitrary colour $\in\{\text{black},\text{white}\}$ to each edge except those connecting some $k$ and $n$ (so that's $n-1\choose 2$ edges). Now pick the colour of edge $kn$  deterministically to make vertex $k$ incident with an even number of black edges. In the end, $n$ is automatically incident with an even number of black edges.

Comment: I was confused by the notation, but now I get it. For future readers that have the same confusion: *all* edges connecting to $n$ are initially uncolored but no others. In first reading I thought that either only $kn$ for some fixed $k$ or all edges connected to $n$ *and* all edges connected to some fixed $k$ were left uncolored and nothing made sense. However only $n$ is fixed, and the smart deterministic coloring of $kn$ takes place for every $k < n$.